# Auto refresh div without refreshing the whole page

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there a simple way to auto refresh a div without refreshing the whole page?

```
<div class="refresh-this">
  <div class="left">
    Left
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    Right
  </div>
</div>
```

You'll see in the codepen, I'm adding a random class each time the page refreshes

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JOjwLz

Comment: Using javascript manipulate the fields you want to update.

Comment: you'll need an event to "autorefresh" or you could use [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Comment: Check this out: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WXNPbM but your code have many issue!

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can use this jquery script.

```
function randomClass() {

    let classes = ['random-1','random-2', 'random-3'];
    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * classes.length);

    return classes[index];
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    let leftClass, rightClass;
    while (leftClass == rightClass) {
        leftClass = randomClass();
        rightClass = randomClass();
    }
    $('.left').addClass(leftClass);
     $('.left').removeClass(rightClass);
    $('.right').addClass(rightClass);
     $('.right').removeClass(leftClass);
    }, 1000);
});
```

At the last I add `1000` its means every 1 seconds later this div will be refresh. If you want you can change the time.
If you have any question feel free for asking me.